# Smart Contract in website framework?

Tags: blockchain, javascript, react

Let's say you have a Smart Contract which allows users to enter in a list by paying 0.05 ETH

How would you implement the front-end / what framework would you choose?

For example, I saw someone who said that ideally would be to use React, a javascript library to build interfaces.

Any other options that are available? Could the Smart Contract be integrated by writing native javascript? I am really confused to be honest, mainly because I still have to understand what my next step is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web3js is a native js library to interact with block chain and smart contract then you can freely choose any to build your frontend

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks for the kind answer ;) It definitely helped me to move forward. Unfortunately stackexchange doesn't allow me to rate answer as useful yet :(

Comment: Okay no problems! You can accept the answer if it satisfy your question, by the way ;)